# Remove tags inside attributes

Tags: php, regex, dom

I have this string that was passed to a Text_Diff...

```
<?php
$left_string = '<div class="class1" style="display:block;">Some Text<del> Orig</del></div>';
$right_string = '<div class="class1" style="<ins>color:#FFF;</ins>;display:block;">Some Text</div>';
```

There are only two possible tags namely: del and ins. I'm not to remove these tags if ever they are not inside tags. But need to remove them when they are inside attributes.

Comment: parse the string into DOM, then traverse the attributes searching for tags with preg_filter

Comment: desired output for $right_string would be:

    $right_string = '<div class="class1" style="color:#FFF;display:block;">Some Text</div>'; note: only inside the style attribute... but note that it could be any attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use search by using the following regular expression:

```
(?<=style=)([\w\W]+)(?:<ins>|<del>)([\w\W\s]+)(?:<\/ins>|<\/del>)([\w\W]*)(?=">)
```

The value of the attribute is the text that matches with backward links:

```
([\w\W]+) == $1

([\w\W\s]+) == $2

([\w\W]*) == $3
```

Then this combination will give you the required value for the attribute:

```
$1$2$3
```

For this input string:

```
<div class="class1" style="display:block;">Some Text<del> Orig</del></div>
```

You will get the result:

`<div class="class1" style="display:block;">Some Text<del> Orig</del></div>`

For this input string:

`<div class="class1" style="<ins>color:#FFF;</ins>;display:block;">Some Text</div>`

You will get the result:

`<div class="class1" style="color:#FFF;;display:block;">Some Text</div>`

For this input string:

`<div class="class1" style=";display:block;<ins>color:#FFF;</ins>">Some Text</div>`

You will get the result:

`<div class="class1" style=";display:block;color:#FFF;">Some Text</div>`

See demo here: https://regex101.com/r/3XKv5s/1

---

For any attribute, not only `style`:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]=")([\w\W]*)(?:<ins>|<del>)([\w\W\s]*)(?:<\/ins>|<\/del>)([\w\W]*)(?=">)
```

See demo here: https://regex101.com/r/3XKv5s/2

Comment: Alkesey, what if the diff happens on another attribute? it doesn't only happen on style. It could be on class, src, etc.